# Php SimpleXML find specific child node in any level in the parent

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXML to parse my xml file. I'm looping through it and in each node I need to get value of one specific tag. Here is an example

```
<node>
    <child1></child1>
    <findme></findme>
    <child2></child2>
</node>
<node>
    <child1>
        <findme></findme>
    </child1>
    <child2></child2>
</node>
<node>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2>
      <another>
            <findme></findme>
      </another>
    </child2>
</node>
```

In each node I need to get `findme` tag. But I don't know in which level it can be, all I know is a tagname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only decision I came up with was to use this recursive function

```
foreach($xml as $prod){
  ...
  $findme = getNode($prod, 'fabric');
  ...
}

function getNode($obj, $node) {
    if($obj->getName() == $node) { 
        return $obj;
    }
    foreach ($obj->children() as $child) {
        $findme = getNode($child, $node);
        if($findme) return $findme;
    }
}
```

---

**Updated**

Also as was suggested in comments we can use DOMDocument class like this:

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->LoadXML($xmlStr);
 $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('node');

 foreach($nodes as $node)
 { 
    $findme = $node->getElementsByTagName("findme")->item(0);
    echo $findme->textContent."\r";
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `XPath` to find target element because you don't know level of target tag. Php [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class has [`xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method that find element by `XPath`.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
$result = $xml->xpath('//findme');
foreach($result as $elem)
{ 
    echo $elem;
}
```

You can check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/WsMvi)

---

**Edit:**

You need to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class if you want to find specific element in another element.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlStr);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('node');
foreach($nodes as $node)
{ 
   echo $node->getElementsByTagName("findme")->item(0)->textContent;
}
```

You can check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/aEEu9)

Comment: The thing is I need to find my tag when work directly with one single node(when looping). Using  xpath('//findme') - it searches in whole document..

Comment: @Jeremy You can also find specific element in `<node>` using `xpath('//node//findme')`. See https://3v4l.org/fKNWa

Comment: @Jeremy Is my answer useful?

Comment: xpath did not help me, but I am actually found the way to solve this with custom recursive function

Comment: @Jeremy But it worked and did what you said in question. So what is problem in it?

Comment: So I looping through my file. Here I in some <node>,  and I need to find my tag in it. I cant use xpath('//node//findme') because I already in my node and I cant use xpath('//findme') because it searches in whole document. I tried use xpath in different ways, but looks like it just not working for this particular situation..

Comment: @Jeremy So you should use `DOMDocument` class instead of `SimpleXML`. Check https://3v4l.org/aEEu9

Answer (score 1):

Had been looking for the same. After some tinkering, realized that the following would work.

`$parent->xpath('.//findme')`

Here, `.` means current level, and `//` implies anywhere within the current level/node.